# How to get a Jackson TypeReference from certain type of List<some class>?

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I know how to get a TypeReference from known classes, such as:

```
        List<MyPojo> list = buildMyPojoList();
        String json = getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(list);
        getObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<MyPojo>>(){});
```

But when I get something like `<Class<? extend Pojo>>` rather than known class `<MyPojo>`, is it still possible to get a TypeReference like above? Or any other way to do `readValue()` given only the string and the class? (the json string contain info of a list of that given class)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found the answer by myself...

Could use things like:

```
    objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(List.class, Class<?> myClass)
```

not sure whether working or not, still trying...